# Latitude and Longitude, x and y, and differences when plotting them: geosphere and ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, latitude-longitude, ggmap, geosphere

I'm using latitude and longitude data and trying to graphically display metrics at each point of a map of Stockholm (based on proximity to that point).  I am more interested in the points being equally spaced on the image, rather than equally spaced in actual distance: in this sense, I understand that distances between latitude points at the equator are longer than they are along the polar circles, and this might be a crucial to the question.

My goal was to divide up the map into a grid of approximately 1 km increments in both the x and y direction.  As such, I took the minimum and maximum latitude and longitude, calculated their x and y distances from the centre of Stockholm, and then divided the span of the latitudes and longitudes by the span of the x and y coordinates (using geosphere).  I did this because I wanted the points to be equally spaced when plotting them (otherwise, there would be less distance between x points at the top compared to the bottom of the map due to proximity to the equator).

I then plotted these points on the map (using ggmap), and observed that there is more distance between points in the y direction than the x direction.  I suppose the map could be simply drawn in a distorted manner, but it seems a little bit too distorted to believe.  I suspect I might be doing something wrong, but can't find what it might be.

Code example below:

```
library("ggmap")
library("RgoogleMaps")
library("geosphere")

stockholm <- get_map("stockholm", zoom=11)
ggmap(stockholm)

places <- c('Tensta', 'Hanviken')

pos <- data.frame(Places = places, lat = NA, lon = NA, x = NA, y = NA)
reflatlon = getGeoCode('Stockholm, Sweden')

for(i in 1:length(places)) {
  latlon <- getGeoCode(paste0(places[i], ', Stockholm'))
  pos$lat[i] <- as.numeric(latlon[1])
  pos$lon[i] <- as.numeric(latlon[2])

  dist_y <- distGeo(c(latlon[1], reflatlon[2]), reflatlon) * sign(latlon[1] - reflatlon[1]) # same longitude
  dist_x <- distGeo(c(reflatlon[1], latlon[2]), reflatlon) * sign(latlon[2] - reflatlon[2]) # same latitude

  pos$x[i] <- dist_x
  pos$y[i] <- dist_y
}

deglatperm <- ( max(pos$lat) - min(pos$lat) ) / ( max(pos$y) - min(pos$y) ) # degrees latitude per metre
deglonperm <- ( max(pos$lon) - min(pos$lon) ) / ( max(pos$x) - min(pos$x) ) # degrees longitude per metre

seqlat <- seq(min(pos$lat), max(pos$lat), by = deglatperm*1000) # sequence with a point every ~1km
seqlon <- seq(min(pos$lon), max(pos$lon), by = deglonperm*1000) # sequence with a point every ~1km

seqlatlon <- expand.grid(seqlat, seqlon)
names(seqlatlon) <- c('lat', 'lon')

ggmap(stockholm) + geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat), data=seqlatlon)
```

[output plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLcMF.jpg)

As you can see from the output plot, there is at least twice as much distance between points in the y direction as compared to the x direction.

To summarise: the x and y coordinates are obtained using geosphere.  The map is plotted using ggmap.

Am I doing something wrong with geosphere?  Or are maps of latitude and longitude *SO* distorted?  When I open Google Maps, and use the "measure distance" tool approximately between top and bottom, and left and right points,  I get estimates of 16.3 and 16.9 km, whereas the values I get with geosphere are 17 and 32km (x and y) respectively.

If someone could tell me what's going on here, I'd be extremely thankful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to avoid working in any coordinate system the uses degrees instead of distances. In the US I use our State Plane system constantly. It appears that Sweden uses the RT system. Once you get your coordinates out of degrees and into distances from a datum, then you can build your grid using more conventional distances. From there you can put your coordinates back into degrees if you like.

I use the [spTranform](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/sp/docs/spTransform) function for coordinate conversions and use I the [Spatial Reference](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3022/) guide to get the reference codes for the coordinate systems.

```
library("ggmap")
library("RgoogleMaps")
library("geosphere")
library("sp")

stockholm <- get_map("stockholm", zoom=11)
ggmap(stockholm)

places <- c('Tensta', 'Hanviken')

pos <- data.frame(Places = places, lat = NA, lon = NA)
reflatlon <- getGeoCode('Stockholm, Sweden')

for(i in 1:length(places)) {
  latlon <- getGeoCode(paste0(places[i], ', Stockholm'))
  pos$lat[i] <- as.numeric(latlon[1])
  pos$lon[i] <- as.numeric(latlon[2])
}

p <- SpatialPoints(data.frame(pos$lon, pos$lat), proj4string = CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
p <- spTransform(p, CRS("+init=epsg:3022"))

seqx <- seq(min(p@coords[,1]), max(p@coords[,1]), by = 1000)
seqy <- seq(min(p@coords[,2]), max(p@coords[,2]), by = 1000)

pgrid <- expand.grid(seqx, seqy)
pgrid <- SpatialPoints(pgrid, proj4string = CRS("+init=epsg:3022"))
pgrid <- spTransform(pgrid, CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
pgrid <- data.frame(pgrid@coords)

names(pgrid) <- c('lon', 'lat')

ggmap(stockholm) + geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat), data=pgrid)
```

Comment: Great answer - thanks!  So the issue was in my use of geosphere: I didn't realise that coordinate systems were so complex, but it makes sense in hindsight.

So, if I undertand correctly, you transformed the coordinates in a world epsg:4362 to a local epsg:3022 topographic coordinate reference system?

And, in choosing epsg:3022 specifically, did you do this by searching spatialreference.org?  I searched Stockholm and did not obtain this reference, but got 11 different codes.  Or is there a specific/automated way/place for finding which epsg code to use for a specified region?

Thanks again!

Comment: The transformation to a coordinate system that is in units of distance is key. To find the RT90 coordinate system I searched google for "Swedish coordinate system". You'll notice that there are several RT coordinate systems in SR.org. I did first try searching Stockholm in SR, but came up empty handed as well. I don't know of a particular source for finding local coordinate systems (however, projfinder.org does the reverse, which is pretty cool). EPSG is just a catalog number. Each coordinate system is unique and most are recognized by EPSG. Search "geographic coordinate systems". Heavy stuff.

Comment: Also, you may want to post to GIS Stack Exchange if you are looking for other answers. If this works for you you can up vote it or mark it as the answer.

Comment: Great! I was googling about to try to figure it out, but ran into difficulties pretty quickly: heavy stuff indeed! But I think that scaffolds me enough to be able to figure out the relevant coordinate system in future if I'm working with someplace else. Super helpful! This is actually my first StackOverflow post, so I don't have enough 'reputation' to upvote, but will mark it as answered now - didn't notice that button before. Thanks again!

Comment: There's a reason that the web uses WGS 84 for everything - one coordinate system to rule them all - I just think it makes doing distance computations pretty difficult. There's probably a tool out there that will do the distance to degrees conversion for you on the fly correctly. Again GIS stack exchange might shed more light on this problem if you need to do this for a wide diversity of places. Good luck!